# kafka consumer clubbing json event fields in array when loaded high speed data

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am writing a kafka consumer in java.
Expecting normal json event
eg :

```
{"cs-uri": "tcp://teams.microsoft.com:443/","cs(Referer)": "-","cs-auth-group": "/","cs-uri-extension": "-","cs-bytes": "13941","username": "-","src": "10.3.41.215", "dstport": "443","event_time": "Dec 1 06:46:09",...}
```

ProxyEvent class

```
public class ProxyEvent {

    @JsonProperty("cs-uri-scheme")
    String CsUriScheme;
    @JsonProperty("devicetime")
    String DeviceTime;
    @JsonProperty("dst")
    String Dst;
    @JsonProperty("event_source_id")
    String EventSourceId;
    @JsonProperty("log_type")
    String LogType;
    @JsonProperty("time-taken")
    String TimeTaken;
    @JsonProperty("rs(Content-Type)")
    String RsContentType;
    @JsonProperty("dstport")
    String Dstport;
    @JsonProperty("sc-status")
    String ScStatus;
    @JsonProperty("cs-uri-extension")
    String CsUriExtension;
    @JsonProperty("srcport")
    String Srcport;
}
```

but my kafka consumer is somehow clubbing fields with same key and value into json array

like this:

```
{"cs-uri":["tcp://teams.microsoft.com:443/","tcp://teams.microsoft.com:443/"],"cs(Referer)":["-","-"],"dstport":["443","443"],"cs-auth-group":["-","-"],"sc-filter-result":["OBSERVED","OBSERVED"],"@timestamp":"2023-04-18T08:32:52.801Z","srcport":["63917","63917"],"log_type":"KeyValue","sc-bytes":["14767","14767"],"devicetime":["01/12/2022:11:44:19 GMT","01/12/2022:11:44:19 GMT"] ...}
```

Issue is only when there is high speed data coming in
which is > 1000 events per second

I tried putting console consumer events are coming properly there.

issue is with my java consumer which has properties

```
config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
config.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);
config.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
config.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, ProxyEvent.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "10485760");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "10485760");
```

and because of that my kafka consumer is unable to deserialize the event.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "processed-proxy", groupId = "group_proxy")
public void consume(ProxyEvent proxyEvent) {
     logger.info("event consumed {}", proxyEvent);
     ...
}
```

these events are being produced by parser which is written in logstash can that be issue?

Producer

```
output {
    kafka {
        codec => json
        message_key => "%{tenant_uuid}"
        partitioner => "round_robin"
        topic_id => "processed-%{device_type}"
        bootstrap_servers => "${KAFKA_HOST}"
        max_request_size => 10485760
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think Kafka consumer isn't doing this. Your producer is... Otherwise, you need to show your ProxyEvent class. For example, cs-uri field cannot be both a String and Array in your object. Or use StringDeserializer and print out those events instead, which is all console consumer does

Comment: That's the issue I have, I am expecting only strings but same key value fields are getting clubbed which I am unable to deserialize.

Comment: Please share your ProxyEvent class. And your producer code

Comment: Proxyevent class: [link](https://codefile.io/f/8eQ7EDtE6ULneO0ZxBMd)
Producer is logstash kafka output plugin: [link](https://codefile.io/f/PxZxZRCqQwVK6stgegjU)

Comment: Please [edit] your post rather than link to external sites. Refer [mcve] for more details

Comment: If you use the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` to examine the record at that offset, you will see that the problem is in the data sent by the producer, not on the consumer side.

Comment: I tried that, issue is at consumer end only.
Also tried using string deserializer instead of json, events are getting consumed properly in that case

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; show the full stack trace.